# Inverted Indices Data Store on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, lucene, full-text-search

Google App Engine (GAE) provides a way to do Full Text Search (FTS) and store and retrieve documents. The default document ranking is based on a time offset. Is there a way to do a Lucene style Inverted indices look-up and ranking on GAE? If not what are some other options to do this.

Use case: FTS and intelligent ranking of results (at least search query frequency based) for bunch of html pages.

Comment: Are you talking about GAE Search API or GAE Datastore? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/  VS  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/

Comment: I guess more like NDB. Inverted Indices basically store the index as the key and the list of all files containing that key as a value. Each value has an associated rank which in simplest form can be frequency of the key. What would an appropriate query be for this and/or can the search api integrate with this?

Comment: Datastore API and Search API store data in different places, you can however link the two via a reference (= store a key to document into entity, or vice versa). Both support indexes, but Search API has full text search and geo-point search, while Datastore API does not. Datastore is a NoSQL database with indexes and limited queries (fast, distributed, with transactions), while Search API is more like a Lucene (storing documents and indexing parts of them that you define)

Answer (score 1):

Both GAE Datastore and GAE Search API can do query-by-index:

1. Datastore is a NoSQL datastore with [user-defined indexes and limited queries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries). It's a database: fast, distributed and has transactions. Queries are however [quite restricted](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Java_Restrictions_on_queries): They can only span one Entity kind, so no JOINs. Only one inequality filter per query, so no geo-point search is possible. Also, string search is exact, so no sub-string search, regex search or LIKE search is possible.
2. Search API is more like Lucene: you store documents and build indexes from parts of the documents. It supports full-text search and geo-point search (e.g. finding geo-points within certain distance from given geo-point).

If you gave us a more specific use case, we might be able to help you decide which one to use.

Comment: Thanks! Added a use case to the question. If Search API is more like Lucene, how does one go about ranking of search results?

Comment: RTFM? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/options#Python_SortOptions

Comment: Thanks! That seems appropriate.